# Creating a mapping for an existing index with a new type in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I found an article on elasticsearch's site describing how to 'reindex without downtime', but that's not really acceptable every time a new element is introduced that needs to have a custom mapping (http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime/)

Does anyone know why I can't create a mapping for an existing index but a new type in elasticsearch? The type doesn't exist yet, so why not? Maybe I'm missing something and it IS possible? If so, how can that be achieved?

Thanks,
Vladimir

Comment: What have you tried to do? and what's not working? You can always create new type (with its own mapping)

Comment: That's the point -- I don't think I can create a new type with its own mappings. Any time I try I get the following error: {
    "error": "IndexAlreadyExistsException[[tluseravailability] already exists]",
    "status": 400
}

Comment: I think I know what are you doing, I want to verify, Can you write the json you are using to add mapping for the type?

Comment: Here it is: {
    "mappings" : {
        "test" : {
            "properties" : {
                "test1" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed" 
                },
                "test2" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed" 
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

Comment: So, it is new type you want to create? what's mapping you used to create index?

Comment: Yes, it's a new type. I used something similar while creating other types in that same index, but I did it once and for all types in that index. When I try to create the new type I get that exception. So from that I gather that I can't create a new type with it's own mappings under an existing index.

Comment: Your findings is wrong, you can. Do you want me to show how I create new type with its own mapping (if there is existing )??

Comment: Of course I do...that's why I posted this question)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a simple example to create two type mapping in a index, (one after another)

I've used **i1** as index and **t1** and **t2** as types,

1. **Create index**

   ```
   curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/i1"
   ```
2. **Create type 1**

   ```
   curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/i1/t1/_mapping" -d
   {
      "t1": {
         "properties": {
            "field1": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "field2": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      }
   }'
   ```
3. **Create type 2**

   ```
   curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/i1/t2/_mapping" -d'
   {
      "t2": {
         "properties": {
            "field3": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "field4": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      }
   }'
   ```

Now Looking at mapping( `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/i1/_mapping"` ), It seems like it is working.

Hope this helps!! Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the type after the index, and have to set the mapping after index creation.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Elasticsearch 6.0 or above, **an index can have only one type**.
So you have to create an index for your second type or create a custom type that would contain the two types.

For more details : [Removal of multiple types in index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/removal-of-types.html)