# Can I add a field automatically to an elastic search index when the data is being indexed?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I have 2 loggers from 2 different clusters logging into my elasticsearch. logger1 uses indices mydata-cluster1-YYYY.MM.DD and logger2 uses indices mydata-cluster2-YYYY.MM.DD.

I have no way of touching the loggers. So i would like to add a field on the ES side when the data is indexed to show which cluster the data belongs to. Can i use mappings to do this?

Thanks

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098314/elasticsearch-run-script-on-document-insertion-insert-api) might be interesting

Comment: doc says it was deprecated in 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

What if you use the [PUT](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#indices-put-mapping) mapping API, in order to add a field to your index:

```
PUT mydata-cluster1-YYYY.MM.DD/_mapping/mappingtype <-- change the mapping type according to yours 
{
  "properties": {
    "your_field": {
      "type": "text" <--- type of the field
    }
  }
}
```

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354701/creating-a-mapping-for-an-existing-index-with-a-new-type-in-elasticsearch) could come in handy. Hope it helps!